# How to access parent property with the same name

Tags: delphi, inheritance, properties, setter

I need to do some processing before the FormStyle property of my form changes but TForm.SetFormStyle (the property setter) is private, is there some way to override the property but still have access to the parent class property?

```
TMyForm = class(TForm)
private
  procedure MySetFormStyle(Style: TFormStyle);
public
  property FormStyle: TFormStyle read Parent.FormStyle write MySetFormStyle;
end;

TMyForm.MySetFormStyle(Style: TFormStyle);
begin
  if Parent.FormStyle <> Style then
    DoSomething;

  Parent.FormStyle := Style; 
end;
```

I'm using delphi 2010

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That creates a new property rather than overriding the existing property. And in fact it is not possible to override properties. If `SetFormStyle` was virtual then you could override the setter.

You can access the inherited property though. Like this:

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
  private
    function GetFormStyle: TFormStyle;
    procedure SetFormStyle(Value: TFormStyle);
  public
    property FormStyle: TFormStyle read GetFormStyle write SetFormStyle;
  end;

function TMyForm.GetFormStyle: TFormStyle;
begin
  Result := inherited FormStyle;
end;

procedure TMyForm.SetFormStyle(Value: TFormStyle);
begin
  if Value <> FormStyle then
  begin
    DoSomething;
    inherited FormStyle := Value; 
  end;
end;
```

The problem with this is that your property won't displace the `TForm` property in the .dfm files. When the .dfm files are read, `FormStyle` refers to the `TForm` property. You can set your property at runtime if you have a reference to a `TMyForm`.

So, whilst the code above will compile, I don't expect that it will solve your problem. I've answered the direct question of how to access an inherited property from a derived class, but I don't think I've solved your actual problem.

My instincts are that your proposed design, and the code above, is a bad idea. Since modifying form style will result in window re-creation, perhaps what you really need is to override `CreateParams` or `CreateWnd`.

Comment: Yes, changing style at runtime is definitely a bad idea but the people who developed the app I'm mantaning didn't know better so now I have to deal with it. Maybe I should rename DoSomething to PrepareBecauseAllHellAreGonnaBreakLoose.